# Can EXINIT contain more than one command?

Tags: vimrc

I have my EXINIT set to

```
export EXINIT="set ts=4 sw=4 ai nosm nows expandtab"
```

I also want `syn off` to turn off syntax highlighting by default.

How can I add this to EXINIT? Tried using `;` as a the separator but that doesn't work.

I know I can put these commands in `.exrc` file but I want to know if I can simply use EXINIT.  `vi` or `ex` man pages don't talk about EXINIT when checked on my Mac.

Comment: ```III The environment variable EXINIT.                                   
            ¦   The value of $EXINIT is used as an Ex command line. ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**by new line**

```
export EXINIT='
    set ...
    syntax off
    balabala
    balabala
    ...
    '
```

**by |**

```
export EXINIT='set ... | syntax off | balabala | ....'
```

check [:h :|](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar)

Answer (score 2):

Vim uses the `|` (vertical bar) as a command separator. Like:

```
export EXINIT="set ts=4 sw=4 ai nosm nows expandtab|syntax off"
```

See `:help :bar`. The `|` doesn't work with all commands. But there shouldn't be any problems with the commands you would typically use in a `EXINIT` (or `VIMINIT`).